# Show console after build and go in XCode

Tags: xcode

On my previous macbook I had some hidden `defaults` preference defined for XCode that showed console right after I did "Build and Go" for my app. Now on my new MB machine I can't remember which was it. Yes, I know I should've transferred my preferences, lesson learned.

Any of you know where can I find this kind of preference?

Layout used - **All in one**

Comment: This question is about old version of software and contains information irrelevant for current software version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to Xcode → Preferences → Debugging → On Start → "Show Console".

Answer (score 5):

For Xcode 5.1

1. Goto XCode → Behaviours → Edit Behaviours
2. Select "Running/Generates Output"
3. Check "Show" and select debugger with "Variables & Console"